# MongoDB sort by nested array

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am now using mongodb to get what I want.

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("533b66f3e4b038c01f6a427f"),
  "ccNameCount" : [{
      "ccName" : "ATCC",
      "paperCount" : 4660,
      "strainCount" : 9339,
      "version" : 1
    }, {
      "ccName" : "BCC",
      "paperCount" : 24,
      "strainCount" : 41
    }, {
      "ccName" : "BCCM/DCG",
      "paperCount" : 3,
      "strainCount" : 7
    }]
}
```

Sample document is just like this.Now , I want to query the documents whose ccNameCount.ccName = ATCC and sort the result by paperCount.But of cource ,since ccNameCount is an array , just sort by the key ccNameCount will not give me what I want.So , my question is ,what can i do?Using MapReduce?

Answer (score 4):

Your best option is the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Match the "documents" that contain your condition
    // reduces the working size
    { "$match": {
        "ccNameCount.ccName": "ATCC"
    }},

    // Keep the original document, you might not really care about this
    { "$project": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "ccNameCount": "$ccNameCount"
        },
        "ccNameCount": 1
   }},

    // Unwind the array to de-normalize
    { "$unwind": "$ccNameCount" },

    // Now just match those elements (now documents) as your condition
    { "$match": {
        "ccNameCount.ccName": "ATCC"
    }},

    // Sort the results on the now selected "paperCount"
    { "$sort": { "ccNameCount.paperCount": -1 } },

    // Put the documents back to normal if you want
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "ccNameCount": "$_id.ccNameCount"
    }}

])
```

So after this actually "selects" your matching array element, the results can then be sorted by the field in this position. The **`$project`** stages are optional if you want to get the orginal state of the array back in your results, otherwise the stages only select the matching entries and sorts them correctly

Comment: Hi , thank you for your response,I understand now.But I have a very small quesiton.You have two $match operation ,before $unwind and after $unwind,I know their different function ,but what should I to in my java code to make the $match occur two times?

Comment: @Vico_Wu As the comments on the stages state, they are doing two completely different things. The first `$match` filters **documents**. Filtering documents and filtering array items are very different. The second statement **after** the unwind actually selects only the matching elements. So the purpose of the **first** `$match` is to **only** select the documents that do have that matching element. If all of your documents have that field, then the first match is redundant. But if not, it is your best performance gain to first remove the documents that do not match at all.